# Postgres - calculate change in cumulative data

Tags: postgresql

I am gathering data from a few API sources via Python, and adding this to 2 tables in Postgres.

I then use this data to make reports, joining and grouping/filtering the data. Every day I add thousands of rows.

The cost, revenue and sales is always cumulative, meaning that each data point is from t1 for that product and t2 is the time of data retrival.

The latest data pull will therefore include all the previous data down to t1. t1, t2 are timestamp without time zone in Postgres. I currently use Postgres 10.

sample:

```
id, vendor_id, product_id, t1, t2, cost, revenue, sales
1, a, a, 2018-01-01, 2018-04-18, 50, 200, 34
2, a, b, 2018-05-01, 2018-04-18, 10, 100, 10
3, a, c, 2018-01-02, 2018-04-18, 12, 100, 9
4, a, d, 2018-01-03, 2018-04-18, 12, 100, 8
5, b, e, 2018-25-02, 2018-04-18, 12, 100, 7

6, a, a, 2018-01-01, 2018-04-17, 40, 200, 30
7, a, b, 2018-05-01, 2018-04-17, 0, 95, 8
8, a, c, 2018-01-02, 2018-04-17, 10, 12, 5
9, a, d, 2018-01-03, 2018-04-17, 8, 90, 4
10, b, e, 2018-25-02, 2018-04-17, 9, 0-, 3
```

Cost and revenue are from two tables, and I join them on vendor_id, product_id and t2.

Is there a way I can go through all of the data and "shift" it and subtract, so instead of having cumulative data, I will have time series based data?

Should this be done prior to storing it, or better done when making the reports?

For reference, currently if I want a report with change between two times, I do two sub queries, but it seem backwards vs having the data in time series and just aggregate the needed intervals.

```
with report1 as (select ...),
report2 as (select ...)
select .. from report1 left outer join report2 on ...
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

JR

Comment: Great first question mate!

Comment: Thanks! :)

Reply to the above comment:

When doing the subtraction, the time interval would remain, but it would only represent the incremental change from one point to the next , 

While now it represents the running total since t1.

so instead of having
`t1 -- t_n`
`t1 -- t_(n-1)`
`t1 -- t_(n-2)`
`t1 -- t(n-x)`
`[...]`


it would be
`t_(n-1) -- t_n`
`t_(n-2) -- t_(n-1)`
`t_(n-3) -- t_(n-2)`
`[ ..]`

Comment: the only thing thats cumulative is the `sales` column, correct?

Comment: All of them are cumulative: cost, sales, revenue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LAG():

[Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

> ...returns value evaluated at the row that is offset rows before the
>   current row within the partition; if there is no such row, instead
>   return default (which must be of the same type as value). Both offset
>   and default are evaluated with respect to the current row. If omitted,
>   offset defaults to 1 and default to null.

```
with sample_data as (
        select 1 as id, 'a'::text vendor_id, 'a'::text product_id, '2018-01-01'::date as t1, '2018-04-18'::date as t2, 50 as cost, 200 as revenue, 36 as sales
        union all
        select 2 as id, 'a'::text vendor_id, 'b'::text product_id, '2018-01-01'::date as t1, '2018-04-18'::date as t2, 55 as cost, 200 as revenue, 34 as sales
        union all
        select 3 as id, 'a'::text vendor_id, 'a'::text product_id, '2018-01-01'::date as t1, '2018-04-17'::date as t2, 35 as cost, 150 as revenue, 25 as sales
        union all
        select 4 as id, 'a'::text vendor_id, 'b'::text product_id, '2018-01-01'::date as t1, '2018-04-17'::date as t2, 25 as cost, 140 as revenue, 23 as sales
        union all
        select 5 as id, 'a'::text vendor_id, 'a'::text product_id, '2018-01-01'::date as t1, '2018-04-16'::date as t2, 16 as cost, 70 as revenue, 12 as sales
        union all
        select 6 as id, 'a'::text vendor_id, 'b'::text product_id, '2018-01-01'::date as t1, '2018-04-16'::date as t2, 13 as cost, 65 as revenue, 11 as sales
)
select sd.*
    , coalesce(cost - lag(cost) over (partition by vendor_id, product_id order by t2),cost) cost_new
    , coalesce(revenue - lag(revenue) over (partition by vendor_id, product_id order by t2),revenue) revenue_new
    , coalesce(sales - lag(sales) over (partition by vendor_id, product_id order by t2),sales) sales_new
from sample_data sd
order by t2 desc
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work the way I want it to. I will do some more tests, and post here soon! Btw, is this recommended to do prior to storing the data, so it's stored in this format?

Comment: It's always nice to have a copy of your source data 'as is' before you do any ETL, as minor as those changes are; just in case anything goes wrong. So I'd keep copy of the original data, and have the split in a separate table.